# Get 'sharp' metadata after piping through another module

Tags: node.js, sharp

I want to compress an image using `Sharp` image processing library, pass it through an external `quant` library and then get the sharp metadata for it. I want to do this to actually overlay the compressed image size onto the image (during development only).

For a WEBP this is easy because everything is in the sharp pipeline.

```
 // specify the compression
 myImage.webp({ quality: 80 });

 // actually compress it
 var tempBuffer = await myImage.toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true});

 // create a new sharp object to read the metadata
 var compressedImage = sharp(tempBuffer.data);

 // Image data is now available in 
 console.log(compressedImage.info.size / 1024);
```

But when using the `quant` library I'm piping it into a third party library and so it's no longer a sharp object. I need to get the raw buffer out again in the most efficient way. I'm new to Node.js and don't know how to do this.

```
 resizedImage.png()
             .pipe(new quant(['--quality=50-70', '--speed', '1', '-']));
```

Do I need to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-array ?

That seems crazy to me! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You can just pipe it back into `sharp()`like this:

```
resizedImage.png()
            .pipe(new quant(['--quality=50-70', '--speed', '1', '-']))
            .pipe(sharp());
```

Then you can call `metadata()` or further resizing etc. (not that you'd normally do that!)